# How to properly unit test Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm attempting to test an Angular directive, but keep running into the following error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/players/info
```

I believe this is because of references to my controller within my directive definition object, but I'm not sure how to handle it. Below is my directive, then my test:

playerInfo.directive.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('gameApp')
  .directive('playerInfo', playerInfo);

function playerInfo() {
  var directive = {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/app/player/playerInfo.directive.html',
    controller: 'PlayerInfoController',
    controllerAs: 'playerInfo'
  };
  return directive;

  function link(scope, element) {
    var address =   angular.element(element[0].getElementsByClassName('blur'));
    address.on('click', function() {
      address.css({'-webkit-filter': 'none'});
    });
  }
}
```

playerInfoSpec.js:

```
'use strict';

describe('playerInfo directive', function() {
  var element;
  var scope;

  beforeEach(module('gameApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($templateCache) {
    var templateUrl = '/app/player/playerInfo.directive.html';
    var asynchronous = false;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onload = function() {
      $templateCache.put(templateUrl, this.responseText);
    };
    req.open('get', '/base' + templateUrl, asynchronous);
    req.send();
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = '<player-info></player-info>';
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
  }));

  it('should replace the element with the appropriate content', function() {
    scope.$digest();
    expect(element.html()).toContain("Score:");
  });
});
```

My controller uses an injected service to send a `GET` request to `/api/players/info` which is why I believe this error has something to do with my controller reference in my directive definition object.

Comment: How do you "inject service to send a `GET`"? Please post the source of `PlayerInfoController`. Also, have you seen [`$httpBackend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)?

Comment: I was just saying that I hit the endpoint which appears in the error message through a service. This service is injected into my controller through dependency injection; and this API call is the very first thing that happens in my controller.

Comment: Try adding a `$httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/players/info').respond({expectedResponse: 'whatever'});` to your `beforeEach` block (inect `$httpBackend` first) and then `$httpBackend.flush()` at the end of the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller is doing a remote call to /api/players/info.
When unit testing (I guess you are using Karma and Jasmine), you will have to mock the remote call using the ngMock module and the $httpBackend service.

```
'use strict';

describe('playerInfo directive', function() {
  var element;
  var scope;
  var $httpBackend

  beforeEach(module('gameApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($templateCache) {
    var templateUrl = '/app/player/playerInfo.directive.html';
    var asynchronous = false;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onload = function() {
      $templateCache.put(templateUrl, this.responseText);
    };
    req.open('get', '/base' + templateUrl, asynchronous);
    req.send();
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, _$httpBackend_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = '<player-info></player-info>';
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/players/info').respond(200, '');
  }));

  it('should replace the element with the appropriate content', function() {
    scope.$digest();
    expect(element.html()).toContain("Score:");
    $httpBackend.flush()
  });
});
```

There is the full doco [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)
About the [underscores](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject)